# Set custom BackgroundColor of a Excel sheet cell using epplus c#

Tags: c#, openxml, epplus

The problem:

I am using EEPlus.

I am stuck at applying a hex color code, e.g. `#B7DEE8`, for a cell in my Excel sheet.

I got the following (working) code:

```
ws.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
ws.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Gray);
```

But I need something like the following:

```
ws.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor("#B7DEE8");
```

So my question is: is it possible to use hex color codes with EEPlus? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try this

```
Color colFromHex = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B7DEE8");
ws.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
ws.Cells["A1:B1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colFromHex);
```

Comment: I'm using Interop.Excel so I had to use range.Interior.Color but the color from HTML function was what I needed.

Comment: `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml` is really what any one would need.

Answer (score 28):

This is working well.

```
Dim objExcel As New ExcelPackage
Dim Sheet As ExcelWorksheet = objExcel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SheetName")
Sheet.Cells["A1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid
Sheet.Cells["A1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(170, 170, 170))
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not obliged to translate a hexadecimal CSS color formula: You can simply put "0X" as a header of that number, which makes it an integer expression:

```
    var couleur = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(OXB7DEF8);
    Sheet.Cells["A1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    Sheet.Cells["A1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(couleur);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
//fill column A with solid red color from hex
worksheet.Column(1).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
worksheet.Column(1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000"));

//fill row 4 with striped orange background
worksheet.Row(4).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.DarkHorizontal;
worksheet.Row(4).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Orange);
```